# iOS sample to connect a Bluetooth with MFI

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, mfi

I have an application for Android that communicates via Bluetooth with a hardware we develop. Now I need to develop an application for iOS that connects with the same hardware via bluetooth. This hardware makes serial communication via Bluetooth.

I've been researching quite recently and found two outputs:
- Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE).
- Bluetooth with "MFI Program".

Analyzing the smartphone today, both Android as iOS, the best option would be the MFI. Due to availability on older smartphones. Even already started the enrollment process over MFI program.

My question focuses on the development on iOS. And my question is:

**Looking for Objective-C. Is there a difference between connecting to a Bluetooth Low Energy or MFI? Could someone show me an example of connecting via Bluetooth MFI?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MFI is for Bluetooth device Hardware.

Coming to connecting to BLE device from iOS devices, you have to use CoreBluetooth framework.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/52080/introduction-core-bluetooth-building-heart-rate-monitor

Check this link.

Comment: I know that MFI is to develop the hardware. My question in bold explains my question. Looking for iOS, there is a difference between connecting to a BLE and a MFI? Both can connect through CoreBluetooth?

Comment: YES. For connecting to Bluetooth device from iOS devices, we have to use `Core Bluetooth` framework. For communication, MFI will give the protocol for you to read and write to the Bluetooth device

Comment: You know show me an example of connection, reading and writing via bluetooth? Preferably for iOS 6.

Answer (score 5):

As I understand it, devices enrolled in the MFi program use the EAAccessory framework, not CoreBluetooth. Documentation is here: [External Accessory Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009498-SW1).

Sample code [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010079)